# Core Image filter device/simulator outputs

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-image

I'm creating filters in my app using Core Image. I was first testing them on the simulator and all was looking fine. When i switched to a device, the output looks different. For the filter i'm using, here is the code:

```
result = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMatrix" keysAndValues:
                  kCIInputImageKey, image,
                  @"inputRVector", [CIVector vectorWithX:1.00 Y:0.00 Z:0.00 W:0.00],
                  @"inputGVector", [CIVector vectorWithX:0.00 Y:1.00 Z:0.00 W:0.00],
                  @"inputBVector", [CIVector vectorWithX:0.30 Y:0.00 Z:1.00 W:0.00],
                  @"inputAVector", [CIVector vectorWithX:0.42 Y:0.00 Z:0.00 W:1.00],
                  @"inputBiasVector", [CIVector vectorWithX:0.00 Y:0.00 Z:0.06 W:0.00], nil].outputImage;
        
        result = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIVignetteEffect" keysAndValues:
                  kCIInputImageKey, result,
                  kCIInputCenterKey, [CIVector vectorWithX:250 Y:478],
                  kCIInputRadiusKey, @414.36,
                  kCIInputIntensityKey, @0.75,nil].outputImage;

CGRect extent = [result extent];
    CGImageRef cgimage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:extent];
    UIImage *filteredImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimage scale:originalScale orientation:originalOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(cgimage);
    [_filteredImageView setImage:filteredImage];
```

The desired output and what the simulator shows is the following:
[image]

However, when i run it on a device, i get the following output:
[image]

What could be wrong?

Note: the images where taken as screenshots and not through phone or another device. That's the image quality.

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Incorrect image or incorrect filter?

Comment: @Tander the filter's output is correct on simulator and wrong when run on a device. how is that happening? The provided pictures to show you the difference. thanks

Comment: How is result declared? Last time I had a similar issue (Works on Sim and not Device) was due to memory management.

Comment: @Tanderi declare the result as CIImage *result; 
i updated the post on how i'm using the output.

Comment: I had to double-check to see if this image was posted on April 1st. Image on sim = city-scape, image on device = image of cat. Really?!? Methinks you're using totally different source images on the 2 platforms?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i found out the problem. the problem was in the image. I was using different image sizes on each platform.